# Query for adding new field that is the sum of months fields

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, query, date, summarizing

I have a table where fields are a specific month of a year. And I just want to add a new field that is the sum of the months fields that are ticked. Practically speaking I need to know the duration of construction sites which are represented by an entity (one line is one site) by counting the months.

[image]

I know I could do that in Excel too but I still have trouble importing data properly so I'd rather just find an easy fix this time.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Use Field calculator to calculate the number of ticked cells:

```
array_length (array_filter (map_avals( attributes( )),@element='x'))
```

Replace 'x' at the end with the string you use to "tick" the field. Works regardless of how many other attributes you have.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THIS QUICK AND EFFICIENT HELP!! :)

Comment: You're welcome. As a new user, please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235